# SQL count duplicates in another column based on one field per row

Tags: sql, sql-server, dense-rank

I am building out a customer retention report. We identify customers by their email. Here is some sample data from our table:

```
+----------------------------+------------------+-------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--+--+--+--+--+
|           Email            | BrandNewCustomer | RecurringCustomer | ReactivatedCustomer | OrderCount | TotalOrders | Date_Created | Customer_Name | Customer_Address | Customer_City | Customer_State | Customer_Zip | Customer_Country |  |  |  |  |  |
+----------------------------+------------------+-------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--+--+--+--+--+
| zyw@marketplace.amazon.com |                1 |                 0 |                   0 |          1 |           1 | 41:50.0      | Sha           |              990 | BRO           | NY             |          112 | US               |  |  |  |  |  |
| zyu@gmail.com              |                1 |                 0 |                   0 |          1 |           1 | 57:25.0      | Zyu           |              181 | Mia           | FL             |          330 | US               |  |  |  |  |  |
| ZyR@aol.com                |                1 |                 0 |                   0 |          1 |           1 | 10:19.0      | Day           |              581 | Myr           | SC             |          295 | US               |  |  |  |  |  |
| zyr@gmail.com              |                1 |                 0 |                   0 |          1 |           1 | 25:19.0      | Nic           |              173 | Was           | DC             |          200 | US               |  |  |  |  |  |
| zy@gmail.com               |                1 |                 0 |                   0 |          1 |           1 | 19:18.0      | Kim           |              675 | MIA           | FL             |          331 | US               |  |  |  |  |  |
| zyou@gmail.com             |                1 |                 0 |                   0 |          1 |           1 | 40:29.0      | zoe           |              160 | Mob           | AL             |          366 | US               |  |  |  |  |  |
| zyon@yahoo.com             |                1 |                 0 |                   0 |          1 |           1 | 17:21.0      | Zyo           |              84  | Sta           | CT             |          690 | US               |  |  |  |  |  |
| zyo@gmail.com              |                1 |                 0 |                   0 |          2 |           2 | 02:03.0      | Zyo           |              432 | Ell           | GA             |          302 | US               |  |  |  |  |  |
| zyo@gmail.com              |                1 |                 0 |                   0 |          1 |           2 | 12:54.0      | Zyo           |              432 | Ell           | GA             |          302 | US               |  |  |  |  |  |
| zyn@icloud.com             |                1 |                 0 |                   0 |          1 |           1 | 54:56.0      | Zyn           |              916 | Nor           | CA             |          913 | US               |  |  |  |  |  |
| zyl@gmail.com              |                0 |                 1 |                   0 |          3 |           3 | 31:27.0      | Ser           |              123 | Mia           | FL             |          331 | US               |  |  |  |  |  |
| zyk@marketplace.amazon.com |                1 |                 0 |                   0 |          1 |           1 | 44:00.0      | Myr           |              101 | MIA           | FL             |          331 | US               |  |  |  |  |  |
+----------------------------+------------------+-------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--+--+--+--+--+
```

We define our customer by email. So all orders with the same email are marked to be under one customer and then we do calculations on top of that.

Now I am trying to find out about customers whose emails have changed. So to do this we will try to line up customers by their address.

So per each row (so when separated by email), I want to have another column called something like Orders_With_Same_Address_Different_Email. How would I do that?

I have tried doing something with Dense Rank but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Email
,BrandNewCustomer
,RecurringCustomer
,ReactivatedCustomer
,OrderCount
,TotalOrders
,Date_Created
,Customer_Name
,Customer_Address
,Customer_City
,Customer_State
,Customer_Zip
,Customer_Country
,(DENSE_RANK() over (partition by Email order by (case when email <> email then Customer_Address end)  asc) 
+DENSE_RANK() over ( partition by Email order by (case when email <> email then Customer_Address end)  desc) 
- 1) as Orders_With_Same_Name_Different_Email
--*
FROM Customers
```

Comment: instead of dense rank just use count() it can work with the over https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Please share expected o/p sample as well

Comment: This makes negative sense to me: `case when email <> email` - if the intention is to not care about order even though the syntax requires it, replace that whole `CASE` expression with `SELECT NULL`. And maybe even comment that that was the intention. The next maintainer is going to look at that expression and go cross-eyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try counting the email partitioned by address, not by email:

```
select   Email,
         -- ...

         Orders_With_Same_Name_Different_Email = iif(
             (count(email) over (partition by Customer_Address) > 1, 
         1, 0)

from     Customers;
```

But this is a lesson in why you wouldn't use an email as an identifier for a client.  Address is a bad idea as well.  Use something that won't change.  That usually means making an internal identifier, such as something that auto-increments:

```
alter table #customers
add customerId int identity(1,1) primary key not null
```

Now customerId = 1 will always refer to that particular customer.

Comment: does it make sense to use address as an identifier for a client?

Comment: No, that can change as well.  You need something that would never change.  Basically, you should create a new identifier.  I'll edit my answer to give you a little more guidance in that regard.

Comment: We only have access to use email for the identifier. I am trying to use the following line ,count(email) over (partition by Customer_Address) Orders_With_Same_Name_Different_Email but this includes cases when the email is the same (basically it just becomes TotalOrders). Is there any way to account for this? Case when email <> email?

Comment: @Hogan, haha, I wasn't paying attention.

Comment: Sounds like 'customers' isn't really at the 'customer' level.  Take a look at Himanshu Ahulja's answer to see if it helps you.  You may have to re-work it if you want to output all customers but include a 1/0 column.  But his count distinct against an orders-level table is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by customer_address and check the count. This is by the assumption that each customer has one address.

```
   Select * from table where 
  customer_address IN (
  Select customer_address
  From table group by customer_address
  having count(distinct customer_email) 
   >1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want to do, this is how I would solve it:

Note, you don't need the having clause in the CTE but depending on your data it could make it faster.  (That is, if you have a large dataset.)

```
WITH email2addr
(
  select email, count(distinct customer_address) as addr_cnt
  from customers
  group by email
  having count(distinct customer_address) > 1
)

SELECT 
    Email
    ,BrandNewCustomer
    ,RecurringCustomer
    ,ReactivatedCustomer
    ,OrderCount
    ,TotalOrders
    ,Date_Created
    ,Customer_Name
    ,Customer_Address
    ,Customer_City
    ,Customer_State
    ,Customer_Zip
    ,Customer_Country
    CASE when coalese(email2addr.addr_cnt,1) > 1 then 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as has_more_than_1_email 
from customers
left join email2addr on customers.email = email2addr.email
```